# Opening url with video or audio in IE 8 under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, windows-media-player

Using Win7-64 Ultimate RTM and IE 8, opening an URL with wma or wmv does not work.

Opening the same file in FireFox or Opera is no problem, they use Windows Media Player just fine.

The file associations for both file types are set to Windows Media Player so it must be another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/GettingReadyforWindows7/thread/12fd4dd3-344b-4f5e-9201-ccaf2eefae13) (found on Social answers @ Microsoft) by Charles Fook

**Fix:**

Open notepad paste these lines in

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.avi]
@="WMP11.AssocFile.AVI"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.asf]
@="WMP11.AssocFile.ASF"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.wmv]
@="WMP11.AssocFile.WMV"
```

- Save file to your desktop 'filename'.reg -- make sure you change it from saving as a .txt file to a "." file
- Open the file and agree to adjust registry
- Open your movies

Comment: This works, I found a solution to this and fixed it a week ago, but had forgotten the what registry values to change. The question then is why is it like this in a new install of Win 7  / IE 8 with no extra codecs or other media players.

Comment: It might be cleared as a default, since IE 8 doesn't have to be your default browser

Comment: It is my default browser

Comment: Just because it is, doesn't mean Windows automatically sets it as being so ;-)